# Refresh php blade foreach loop from jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, foreach

So in my html I have `foreach` cycle, and at some moment some data gets posted from javascript, and I'd like to append it when in is added to the database.

So I need to **refresh foreach** somehow **without refreshing the whole page** (I could just append() data from javascript, but there is too mush to make string out of them).

Any suggestions? Any possible help would be highly appreciated.

The loop itself is placed in table rows:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($tags as $tag)
        <tr data-row-id="{{$tag->id}}">
            <td class="text-left " style="">{{$tag->id }}</td>
            <td class="text-left " style="">{{$tag->title}}</td>
            <td class="text-right" style=""><a href="#" name="{{$tag->id}}" data-name="{{$tag->title }}" class="btn-floating btn-medium waves-effect waves-light red delete-tag"><i class="material-icons left white-text" name="{{$tag->id}}">delete</i></a></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

and my javascript posts the data of new tag, and gets its full information back from controller

Comment: It would be very useful if you posted some code.

Comment: What's wrong with `.append()`?

Comment: @Rudi I don't know why, but if I try to append all the data manually, the structure of the table gets broken

Comment: It should work fine if you add another `tr` for each data item. You can instead also use `.clone()` to copy an existing html structure and then replace the data. Or you can render the html on the server and just append the whole string.

Comment: how do you make this inside HTML? I know Laravel have it, but I have try to find out what it are called and how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I just moved the whole table into the separate particular view, and it gets loaded again after posting is completed. Probably not the best option, but still working one